# What is the benefit of moving a range of elements in a vector vs. copying?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, move, stdvector

Consider the following snippet (saw something analogous to this in a large simulation code)

```
std::vector<int> v1{1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
std::vector<int> v2;

std::move(v1.begin() + 2, v1.end(), back_inserter(v2));
```

Here, I am moving a range of elements from `v1` to `v2`, but is there any particular advantage to doing this vs. copying? I do not actually see what the advantage of the `move` here would be since it's operating on a range of `int`s. In fact, I do not believe any move is occurring since we are dealing with POD types.

If we instead wanted to transfer the entire `v1` to `v2`, then we could do:

```
v2 = std::move(v1);
```

The cast here would allow `v2` to now own the pointer to the contiguous range of memory previously owned by `v1`, thus avoiding a copy.

But in the former move of a range of elements, I do not see the usefulness.

Comment: Think about a vector of vectors

Comment: @Mat Right, in that case, I see a benefit. I just don't see the use in the above case. The code that I saw was indeed a vector of ints, which move applied to a contiguous range of elements in the vector.

Comment: As you correctly note, move semantics for PODs are the same as copy semantics. For a type which actually implements move constructor and/or move assignment more efficiently would you notice the difference.

Comment: Sometimes you need to copy, sometimes you need to move. For this specific use-case your call to `std::move` (in the first example) is semantically no different from `std::copy` followed by `v1.erase(...)`, but why do that when a single call to `std::move` would suffice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Here, I am moving a range of elements from `v1` to `v2`, but is there any
> particular advantage to doing this vs. copying?

**No**. Here is all happened just a range coping, because your usage of `std::move` for primitive types just do coping. Therefore it does the same as simple if you would have:

```
std::vector<int> v2{v1.begin() + 2, v1.end()};
```

Therefore you are correct about the findings. However, it is called [fundamental types/ primitive types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types), not PODs.

---

> But in the former move of a range of elements, I don't see the usefulness.

Consider the case of `std::vector</*expensive copy type*/>`, in which it makes sense to have a move of the underlying range elements, whenever is possible.

For instance consider the `std::vector<std::string>` case

```
std::vector<std::string> v1{ "1","2","3","4","5","6","7" };
std::vector<std::string> v2;
// reserve memory for unwanted reallocations
v2.reserve(std::distance(v1.begin() + 2, v1.end()));

// moves the string element in the range
std::move(v1.begin() + 2, v1.end(), back_inserter(v2));

// v1 now: 1 2
// v2 now: 3 4 5 6 7
```

**([See a demo here](https://godbolt.org/z/eMa4T8))**

---

As a side note, instead of `std::move` the range in a separate line, for iterators, one could also use [`std::make_move_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/make_move_iterator), to do the range move construction while declaration (if make sence).

```
#include <iterator> // std::make_move_iterator

std::vector<std::string> v1{ "1","2","3","4","5","6","7" };
std::vector<std::string> v2{ std::make_move_iterator(v1.begin() + 2),
   std::make_move_iterator(v1.end()) };
```